# php foreach() in foreach()

Tags: php, file, list, foreach, lines

I am trying to open multiple files then split each file by line. I am using this with one `foreach()` to browse through files and another `foreach()` inside of it to split the file's lines.

```
$dir = '../mydir';
$files = scandir($dir, 1);
foreach($files as $input){
    if(($input!==".")&&($input!=="..")){
        $myfile="../mydir/".$input;
        $fh = fopen($myfile, 'r');
        echo $input."... ";
        $input = substr($input,0,-4);
        $FN = "../mydir/out.".$input.".xls";
        $FH = fopen($FN, 'w') or die("Can't open file!");
        $lines = file($myFile);
        foreach($lines as $line) {
        list($OPT1,$OPT2) = explode(",", $line);
            fwrite($FH, $OPT1);     
        }
        echo "Done.";
    }
}
```

But my `$OPT1` is empty.

Comment: can you put a `print_r($lines);` right after `$lines = file($myFile);` and report the result here?

Comment: You are using `$myfile` and `$myFile`.

Comment: @TaZ, those eagle eyes.

Comment: yes, it was lower-/uppercase F

Comment: Also look into `glob()` and `file()` and `str_getcsv()` for minimizing your code. Note that you aren't creating Excel files, but `.csv` output.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `$fh = fopen($myfile,'r')` is locking the file so `file()` can't access it. You don't appear to be using that file handle (indeed you are overwriting the variable later) so just remove that line and you should be good.

EDIT: Oh, and apparently variable names are case-sensetive. You can't interchange `$myfile` and `$myFile`.